# the "QUITE" tag in Cambridge Dictionary

Tags: dictionaries

According to Cambridge Dictionary, [fairly](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/fairly) means "more than average, but less than very" while "[quite](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/quite?q=QUITE)" means "completely".

I totally understand the definition of them, though I don't understand the "QUITE" tag in the definition of "fairly".

[image]

What does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed confusing, because the word itself has two contradictory meanings. If you scroll through the *entire* entry for *[quite](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/quite)*, you will find them both:

> B1. completely

> A2. [UK] a little or a lot but not completely ([US] usually *fairly*, *pretty*)

Likewise, to consult their rivals at Oxford: *[quite](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/quite)*

> 1. (British English) (not used with a negative) to some degree
>          *synonym* fairly, pretty

> 2. to the greatest possible degree
>          *synonym* completely, absolutely, entirely

In the Cambridge entry, they use *quite* to indicate the broad sense of *to a moderately high level* as opposed to its other, unrelated meaning of *in a fair manner*, or as they put it, *in the right way*. Under the entry from the Cambridge Academic Content Dictionary further down, they say *to some degree* instead of *quite* for this sense.

In American English, *quite* is quite strong; if my girlfriend is *quite angry* then she's *very angry*, maybe even *extremely angry*. In British and Australian usage, she might merely be *reasonably angry* or *kind of angry*. Unfortunately, beyond that you can only infer which sense is intended from context; there are [no simple clues](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3452/ambiguity-of-quite).

Comment: it used to be common in British upper-class speech to use "quite" in the sense of "completely, absolutely, entirely", in situations where there is no doubt of the meaning (before an absolute adjective not normally modified), so that a girl might be quite beautiful, a party quite wonderful, a pianist's playing quite extraordinary, etc. The same people might also say, using the other meaning, that an egg sandwich was quite good, or a train journey quite long.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Is this a case where aristocratic understatement gets in the way of interpretation? I notice the same divergence with *rather*, whose Cambridge entries are equally maddening: *quite; to a slight degree* but then *very; to a large degree*.

Comment: I think the 'posh' usage is dying out, if it hasn't gone altogether.